# Laravel 4.2 auto loading

Tags: autoload, laravel-4.2

I have a products table in the database. This table loads the nav ul in the header of every page.

I did this in Codeigniter by auto loading a model that fetches the data in the constructor method.

What would be the best way to do this in Laravel? (4.2)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

composer dumpautoload

This solved my problems for me.
It added the following line of code to the autoload_classmap.php file

'Product' => $baseDir . '/app/Models/Product.php'